# ORA-04067: not executed, package body does not exist

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, package

I am working on ASp.net project with backend Oracle DB.

I created a new package with stored procedures to the DB. and Called a stored procedure from package. I am getting following error.

```
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "WB_APP_MANAGER.WB_PCK_APP_MANAGER" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "WB_APP_MANAGER.WB_PCK_APP_MANAGER"
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Please let me know How to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Do we really need an ora-04067 tag? This is the only question on the site with it; I'd think that just the oracle tag would be sufficient. Otherwise we'll end up having a bunch of tags specific to each and every compiler, database, OS, etc. error code out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your package specification may be in place but your package body seems to be missing. For any package which is executed the package body must also exist.

```
select object_type  
from   dba_objects 
where  object_name = 'WB_PCK_APP_MANAGER';
```

The above query must report both PACKAGE and PACKAGE BODY.

If PACKAGE BODY is not reported by the query you need to create the package body.

create or replace package body WB_PCK_APP_MANAGER as

Comment: how to create package body?

Answer (score 2):

- check if the name is correct - you didn't misspelled it;
- check if it is compiled;
- check if WB_APP_MANAGER has proper rights to WB_PCK_APP_MANAGER:

> ```
> select owner, object_name, object_type  
> from   dba_objects 
> where  object_name = 'WB_PCK_APP_MANAGER';
> ```

Comment: im using oracle sql developer, Please tell me how to change owner